# Are Poisson distributions only for arrivals?

Tags: distributions, interarrival-time

I have this data set:

```
4.6093  3.8583  5.2921 11.8326  3.3745 14.3956 
2.4541  1.1305  1.1191  2.9973  4.141   2.0066 
2.7272  8.7227  2.1489  3.0065  2.338   2.6579 
2.6083  4.8375  0.2878  2.6055  1.6949  0.3578 
9.5841  1.7347  2.9482  6.7692 12.1024  4.1612
```

I'm trying to match it to a distribution. I graphed it in a histogram and it looked to me to match the Poisson distribution.

When I learned about the Poisson distribution, I thought it was used for arrivals but these are service times.  Is it possible for these to follow a Poisson distribution or is it another distribution?

Answer (score 5):

It certainly does *not* look like Poisson data: Poisson distributions can only take on count values (i.e. whole numbers). The fact that there are decimals lets you know immediately know it cannot be Poisson.

If you are looking for distributions that are often used to model time to event, I would suggest looking at the exponential and Weibull distributions.

Comment: +1 I'd also have suggested the Gamma as a possible choice. Looking at a Q-Q plot vs exponential scores, the exponential doesn't seem too bad, but either of the other two would fit the left end better.

Comment: @Glen_b: yes, I certainly agree that gamma is another viable alternative. My experience is that in the field of survival analysis, the Weibull distribution is often preferred, although my only explanation for that the reason for this is that those who deal with survival analysis feel comfortable thinking about hazard rates and it's easier to understand the relation between hazard rates and the shape parameter for Weibull than for the gamma distribution.

Comment: Oh, and the proportional hazards and aft Weibull are identical (up to a linear transformation of variables). Neither of these are compelling reasons for choosing the Weibull over the gamma, of course.

Comment: In the case of service times, the gamma occurs (for example) as the time to the completion of $k$ independent exponentially-distributed service-components (each with the same scale), so it's often a reasonable first approximation in cases where there's several parts or stages to service.

Comment: @Glen_b: the theoretical motivation for gamma distribution is a nice aspect. The Weibull distribution apparently [ran into trouble with the reviewers](ftp://132.247.45.41/ExperimentsDesign/Weibull-ASME-Paper-1951.pdf) for not having theoretical motivation (see the middle of the second column on page 1).

Answer (score 1):

A Poisson($\lambda$) random variable is discrete, therefore only takes integer values (0, 1, ...). However, there is a link between the Poisson and Exponential distributions. If an event occurs according to a Poisson process, i.e. if the number of events happening in an interval of length $t$ follows a Poisson ($\lambda t $) distribution, then the elapsed time between two events has an Exponential ($\lambda$) distribution, where the mean of the Exponential is  $1/\lambda$.

In your case, if our data actually represents elapsed times between events, Exponential might be a good choice. In this context, other choices would include Weibull and Gamma.